# How do I convert a series of similar lines into a for loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop, foundation

I'm programming an app for the iPhone.  I'm not very good with loops just yet.  How do I shorten this code into  a for loop?

```
if(CGRectContainsRect([space1 frame], [box frame])){

  space1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"];
 }
 else if(CGRectContainsRect([space2 frame], [box frame])){

  space2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"];
 }
 else if(CGRectContainsRect([space3 frame], [box frame])){

  space3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"];
 }
 else if(CGRectContainsRect([space4 frame], [box frame])){

  space4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"];
 }
 else if(CGRectContainsRect([space5 frame], [box frame])){

  space5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"];
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSArray * spaces = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:space1, space2, space3, space4, space5, nil];
for (Space * space in spaces) {
  if (CGRectContainsRect([space frame], [box frame])) {
    space.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"];
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 errors, Spaces undeclared and selector element does not have a valid type

Comment: @NextRev - check your capitalization.

Comment: I copied it exactly.  Still says Space undeclared

Comment: @NextRev That's because I have no idea what kind of objects `space1` ... `space5` are, and so I just made up the `Space` class.  Change that to whatever type they're supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry bout that, I'm new to this stuff, they are UIImageViews.  I'm actually trying to detect when the user slides a finger across these UIImageViews without lifting the finger, and have code executed as they pass over each UIImageView.  Is this something complicated or is there a short line of code like this for loop you provided?